# Power Series and Frobenius, when i use on this question?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, frobenius-method

I have a question like this

Find the power series solution of the equation $y'' + ty' + 3y = 0$ near the point $t_0=0$

When I solve this problem I couldn't see easily which is $P(x), Q(x)$ in this question.

And which method I must use for this.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need Frobenius here, $t=0$ is not a singular point.

Comment: Simply plug $y:=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nt^n$ and its first and second derivative into your differential equation, and identify the coefficient in each degree.

Comment: @user170231 how can i understand t= 0 is not singular point, when i looked frobenius questions such as x^2y'' + xy' + (x-4)y = 0 i can see P(x) = x^2 , Q(x) = x and R(x) = (x-4) but in this question y'' has no any x or anything. This makes me confuse.

Comment: "$y''$ has no $x$ or anything" $\implies P(x)=1$

Comment: @user170231 thank you so much, this helps me so much

Comment: Please review https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method. Your P,Q,R do not match with it. Your equation is $$t^2y''+tp(t)y'+q(t)y=0$$ where  $p(t)=t^2$ and $q(t)=3t^2$.